# NS_ERROR_XPC_BAD_CONVERT_JS

Tags: javascript, dom

I'm getting this error after trying to "appendChild" to an element that was just created (in for loop).
What does this error mean?
I suppose it's not possible to append sth. to an element that doesn't really exist in DOM.
How do I fix it?
"innerHTML" works, but I don't think it's really clean and proper way to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's nothing wrong with innerHTML if you don't need to add events to the new element.
You can add events later using standard methods anyway